# What is wrong with the below selenuim 2/webdriver test?

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have trouble automating a simple JSF login page that takes 4 inputs (client code, system code, user and password) and takes to the administration page. The below test is behaving differently with each of the drivers and all of them are unsuccessful. I have looked at the html code from the browser (view source) and I see all the input type elements are present with proper id's.

### UPDATE

I was able to make the code work correctly with Firefox with the below change (submitting the form by explicitly clicking on the button rather than submitting he form). But other drivers are showing the same erroneous behavior as described.

```
driver.findElement(By.className("af_commandButton")).click();
```

---

Code

```
import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LoginPage
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        // WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        // WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        try
        {
            driver.get("http://domain:port/coco/webapp/login/login.faces");

            driver.findElement(By.id("clientCode")).sendKeys("coco");
            driver.findElement(By.id("systemCode")).sendKeys("consumer");
            driver.findElement(By.id("userId")).sendKeys("ffadmin");
            driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("password1");

            driver.findElement(By.id("LoginloginForm")).submit();
            // driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

            Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains("Administration"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

**Chrome**

Incorrectly filling in the information as shown below

[image]

**Internet Explorer**

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == clientCode (WARNING: The server did not pr
ovide any stacktrace information)
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:409)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:192)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:209)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$1.findElement(By.java:66)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:184)
    at LoginPage.main(LoginPage.java:22)
```

**FireFox**

Fills in the information properly as shown below but nothing happens when the form is submitted with the posted code and I get the shown exception

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: null
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:20)
    at junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:27)
    at LoginPage.main(LoginPage.java:30)
```

**HtmlUnitDriver**

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Cannot locate element used to submit form
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_24'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submitForm(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:155)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitWebElement.submit(HtmlUnitWebElement.java:108)
    at LoginPage.main(LoginPage.java:27)
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <meta name="generator" content=
    "HTML Tidy for Windows (vers 14 February 2006), see www.w3.org">
    <meta name="generator" content="Apache Trinidad">
    <link rel="stylesheet" charset="UTF-8" type="text/css" href=
    "/coco/webapp/adf/styles/cache/interconnect-zcl0st-en-ltr-webkit.css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
var _AdfWindowOpenError='A popup window blocker has been detected in your browser. Popup blockers interfere with the operation of this application. Please disable your popup blocker or allow popups from this site.';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src=
    "/coco/webapp/adf/jsLibs/Common1_0_8.js">
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
_defaultTZ()
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../skins/interconnect/trinidad-components.css"
    type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/vsFunctions.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/ic-script.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/timezone.js" type=
    "text/javascript">
</script><!--[if lte IE 6]>     

                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Assets/ie6fixes.css" />   

                        <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/ie6-script.js"></script>   

                <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>     

                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Assets/ie7fixes.css" />  

                        <script language="JavaScript" src="../Assets/ie7-script.js"></script>

                <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

                        function disableButton(inputButton)

                        {

                                inputButton.disabled=true;              

                        }

    </script>
    <title></title>
  </head><!-- this is a placehold for application version-->
  <body onload=
  "return _chain('_checkLoad()','readTimeZoneOffset()',this,event)" onunload=
  "_checkUnload(event)">
    <a name="top" id="top"></a><noscript>This page uses JavaScript and requires
    a JavaScript enabled browser.Your browser is not JavaScript
    enabled.</noscript>
    <div class="main-header">
      <div id="header:header-branding" class="header-branding">
        <div id="header:clientbrand" class="client-brand">
          <img id="header:client-image" name="header:client-image" src=
          "/coco/webapp/skins/interconnect/client-logo.gif">
        </div>
      </div>
      <form id="header:_id5" name="header:_id5" style="margin:0px" method=
      "post" onkeypress="return _submitOnEnter(event,'header:_id5');" action=
      "/coco/webapp/login/login.faces">
        <div id="header:basebar" class="basebar">
          <div id="header:finish-right-bar" class="finish-right-bar">
            <ul class="navbar navBarHelp"></ul>
          </div>
        </div><input type="hidden" name=
        "org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value="header:_id5"><span id=
        "tr_header:_id5_Postscript"><input type="hidden" name=
        "org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.STATE" value=
        "!24835796"><script type="text/javascript">
function _header__id5Validator(f,s){return true;}
        </script></span><script type="text/javascript">
_submitFormCheck();
        </script>
      </form>
      <div class="rule"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-menu">
      <div class="rule"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="compact content split-lines">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="locale">
          <form id="localeChanger" name="localeChanger" class="spacingDisplay"
          style="margin:0px" method="post" onkeypress=
          "return _submitOnEnter(event,'localeChanger');" action=
          "/coco/webapp/login/login.faces">
            <div class="locale-links">
              <a href="#" onclick=
              "submitForm('localeChanger',1,{source:'changeLocale_en'});return false;"
              id="changeLocale_en" title="English version" name=
              "changeLocale_en"><img id="flagUSA" src=
              "/coco/webapp/Images/upgrade/flag_english.jpg" alt=
              "English version" border="0" name="flagUSA"></a><a href="#"
              onclick=
              "submitForm('localeChanger',1,{source:'changeLocale_es'});return false;"
              id="changeLocale_es" title="Spanish version" name=
              "changeLocale_es"><img id="flagSPAIN" src=
              "/coco/webapp/Images/upgrade/flag_spanish.jpg" alt=
              "Spanish version" border="0" name="flagSPAIN"></a><a href="#"
              onclick=
              "submitForm('localeChanger',1,{source:'changeLocale_fr'});return false;"
              id="changeLocale_fr" title="French version" name=
              "changeLocale_fr"><img id="flagFRANCE" src=
              "/coco/webapp/Images/upgrade/flag_french.jpg" alt=
              "French version" border="0" name="flagFRANCE"></a><a href="#"
              onclick=
              "submitForm('localeChanger',1,{source:'changeLocale_pt'});return false;"
              id="changeLocale_pt" title="Portuguese version" name=
              "changeLocale_pt"><img id="flagBRASIL" src=
              "/coco/webapp/Images/upgrade/flag_portuguese.jpg" alt=
              "Portuguese version" border="0" name="flagBRASIL"></a>
            </div><input type="hidden" name=
            "org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value=
            "localeChanger"><span id="tr_localeChanger_Postscript"><input type=
            "hidden" name="org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.STATE" value=
            "!24835796"><script type="text/javascript">
function _localeChangerValidator(f,s){return true;}
            </script></span><script type="text/javascript">
_submitFormCheck();
            </script>
          </form>
        </div>
        <form id="LoginloginForm" name="LoginloginForm" class="spacingDisplay"
        style="margin:0px" method="post" onkeypress=
        "return _submitOnEnter(event,'LoginloginForm','login');" action=
        "/coco/webapp/login/login.faces">
          <h1 class="pageTitle">
            User Authentication
          </h1>
          <div class="wizard">
            <div class="section">
              <div class="content">
                <div class="input">
                  <div class="field">
                    <span class="label"><label for="clientCode">Client
                    Code</label></span>
                    <div class="content">
                      <script type="text/javascript">
var _locale='en-US';var _tLocale='en-US';
                      </script><script type="text/javascript" src=
                      "/coco/webapp/adf/jsLibs/resources/LocaleElements_en_US1_0_8.js?loc=en_US">
</script><span class="af_inputText p_AFRequired"><input id="clientCode"
                      name="clientCode" class="af_inputText_content" size="30"
                      maxlength="20" type="text"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <span class="label"><label for="systemCode">System
                    Code</label></span>
                    <div class="content">
                      <span class="af_inputText p_AFRequired"><input id=
                      "systemCode" name="systemCode" class=
                      "af_inputText_content" size="30" maxlength="20" type=
                      "text"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <span class="label"><label for="userId">User
                    Id</label></span>
                    <div class="content">
                      <span class="af_inputText p_AFRequired"><input id=
                      "userId" name="userId" class="af_inputText_content" size=
                      "30" maxlength="20" type="text"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field">
                    <span class="label"><label for=
                    "password">Password</label></span>
                    <div class="content">
                      <span class="af_inputText p_AFRequired"><input id=
                      "password" name="password" onkeydown=
                      "return _clearPassword(this, event);" class=
                      "af_inputText_content" size="30" maxlength="20" type=
                      "password"></span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div><img class="wizard-graphic" src=
                "../Images/upgrade/safe_box.jpg">
                <div class="section">
                  <button id="login" name="login" type="button" onclick=
                  "submitForm('LoginloginForm',1,{source:'login'});return false;"
                  class="action af_commandButton">Log In</button><button id=
                  "forgotPassword" name="forgotPassword" type="button" class=
                  "action af_goButton" onclick=
                  "document.location='../forgotpassword/ForgotPassword.faces'">Password
                  Help</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="legalNoticeLogin">
            <div class="section">
              <div class="content">
                <div id="legalCopy" class="copy">
                  <div class="xcopy af_outputDocument">
                    <p class="af_outputDocument_paragraph">
                      <b>IMPORTANT - READ CAREFULLY</b>
                    </p>
                    <p class="af_outputDocument_paragraph">
                      The private Web site you are about to enter
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div><input type="hidden" name=
          "org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.FORM" value=
          "LoginloginForm"><span id="tr_LoginloginForm_Postscript"><input type=
          "hidden" name="org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.faces.STATE" value=
          "!24835796"><script type="text/javascript">
function _LoginloginFormValidator(f,s){return true;}
          </script></span><script type="text/javascript">
_submitFormCheck();
          </script>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show us the full html it is trying to work against

Comment: could it be that may be there are several elements with the same id, on your page?

Comment: @Tim Koopmans - added the generated html

Comment: @Carlosz - No the ids are not duplicated...i have added the html to the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it would be one of the following:

```
selenium.click("//button[@id='login']");
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//button[@id='login']")).click();
```

I would avoid using the submit form functionality because it looks like the Log In button click is firing some customised JavaScript, you won't fire this if you use the webDriver form submit functionality.

By trying to click on a button with a specific class you are causing yourself the following problems:

More than 1 element can legally have the same class so you may be clicking on the wrong element.
Multiple classes can be assigned to an element, if more than one class is applied and you are searching for a single class it will not always recognise your element, you can get arouns this with XPath by using the contains function, but if you have a perfectly servicable ID it is madness to use this strategy as using contains will again potentially match multiple elements so you may not click on the one you are expecting to click on.

Example of contains with XPath:

```
selenium.click("//button[contains(@class,'af_commandButton')]");
driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//button[contains(@class,'af_commandButton')]")).click();
```

Comment: " the Log In button click is firing some customised JavaScript, you won't fire this if you use the webDriver form submit functionality." can you let me know where this is documented pls.

Comment: It's not a Selenium issue, it's a knowing how the Browser works issue.

Submitting a form is an HTTP function, not a JavaScript one.  You don't need JavaScript to be enabled to do a POST/GET.

To fire an onClick event in JavaScript you either need to click on the button or code in something to fire the onClick event, it won't just happen by itself by doing an HTTP Post.

Comment: can you also explain why different browser drivers are behaving differently in filling the form? Why is chrome or IE not recognizing the text fields eventhough all of them have unique id's and i am referring them in selenium using those ids? tx

Comment: Because the page it not valid W3C complient HTML, it has a missing </ul>.  Modern browsers do a good job of guessing where the missing tag should go and rendering the page anyway, but each browser will make a different guess as to the structure of the DOM.  It's the different versions of DOM that are causing you problems, some versions of it are probably missing the elements you are trying to populate.

Raise a bug with your dev team to get the page made complient and them try again (Automated testing will eventually always fail in a cross browser environment with non-W3C complient HTML)

Comment: Thx for the tip. I do not see any missing UL tag. Also the I am trying to find tan input element by id and I thought this is the basic thing to work across browsers. Firefox identifies all of them, Chrome incorrectly identifies the input elements and IE complains that it can't find the "clientCode"..this beats me...

Answer (score 1):

For firefox,

If you have any UI element that submits the form, please use that

say `selenium.click("link=submit")`

I think It immediately checks for assertion after submitting the form(which also has failed), but it would take some time for page to load. Try putting some delay after form submit. You can use waitForPageToLoad() or Thread.sleep().

Also if the Text "Administration" appears on page, first retrieve the text using xpath/css locator first and then compare it, it will be faster than reading the whole page source.

I've worked only on Selenium 1, but I'm sure you'll have similar functions in Selenium 2 driver.

**UPDATE**

`selenium.click("//div[@class=\'section\']/button[@id=\'login\']") //this will click on login button. Java code for selenium 1`

I hope this works, otherwise use firebug to copy the xpath/css locator of the login button and use that as argument for selenium click function.

Comment: thx for the response. I've posted the html...can you look at it and suggest what is the best way to submit the response